# Send mail add command as attachment

Tags: linux, sendmail, email

I want to send myself a mail from the tree structure of the box.  I did a

```
# tree > tree.txt
# mail -s "tree strct" email@server.com < tree.txt
```

The error should be high file size

```
postdrop: warning: uid=0: Illegal seek
send-mail: fatal: root(0): queue file write error
```

How can I send a mail with the command tree.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mail is too large, you can try compressing it first:

```
tree | gzip -c | uuencode tree.txt.gz | mail -s "tree strct" email@server.com
```

Answer (score 0):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/10/sending-mails-from-command-line.html

look this link may help !! :D